# Integer initializing and method error

Tags: java, arrays, methods, integer, joptionpane

I'm having trouble with the following... I've removed the none important part of the code so it's not as confusing. All other symbols/variables have been defined and or initialized already.

Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

numsalchange is a seperate method that is determining in a loop if values in the indsaldif array are 0. If they are, it's of course incrementing change.

Change is later being sent to the report method to be displayed. I've tried it several different ways with values that will and will not definitely equal 0. However, each time change is outputted as 0, when I know it should definitely be something else.

I've tried just declaring the change as

```
int change;
```

And then setting it as zero in the method, but it will not let me send it to the method without being initialized in the main.

I have a feeling it is being displayed in the report method as 0, because it is being intialized as zero and sent to report as 0 and not the updated value.

```
public static void main blah(String[] args){

int change = 0;
numsalchange (userinput, change, indsaldif);
report (userinput, oldsalary, newsal, indsaldif, change);


public static void numsalchange(String[] userinput, int change, double[] indsaldif){



    for ( int i=0; i<userinput.length; i++){

        if(indsaldif[i] != 0){
            change++;}}}
    public static void report(String[] userinput, double[] oldsalary, double[] newsal, double[] indsaldif, int change){

            DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            double saldiff = 0;
            for( double i : indsaldif) {
                    saldiff += i;
                }
            String toString;                        
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
            sb.append("PB Incorporated Salary Report \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < userinput.length; i++) {
             sb.append("---------- \nEmployee:"+ userinput[i] + "\nOld Salary: $"+ twoDigits.format(oldsalary[i]) + "\nNew Salary: $" + twoDigits.format(newsal[i]) + "\nSalary Change: $" + twoDigits.format(indsaldif[i])+"\n");
                 //**  
                                }
                sb.append("---------- \nTotal Employee Salary Increase: $" + twoDigits.format(saldiff) + "\n# of Salary Increases: " + change);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in `change` to your method, Java passes a copy of that value.  The method may change the copy, but it's not reflected in the original `change` you declared in `main`.

To maintain your `change` count throughout the class, have `numsalchange` declare a local variable initialized to 0, and it can increment it as it sees fit.  Then it should `return` that value, and `main` can add that returned value to `change`.

Answer (score 1):

You can return change from numsalchange

```
  change = numsalchange (userinput, change, indsaldif);
  ...

public static void numsalchange(String[] userinput, int change, double[] indsaldif){
  ...
  return change;
}
```

You may also make your `change` variable static field of your class

```
private static int change;
```